# How to covert a string of ascii codes to text?

Tags: javascript, ascii

I have a list of ascii character codes returned as '104,101,108,108,111', and I am trying to translate those back to a string:

```
response = '104,101,108,108,111'
String.fromCharCode(response)
```

When I pass this to `String.fromCharCode(response)` then I get `' '` as response, but when I pass input like below I am able to get proper response:

```
String.fromCharCode(104,101,108,108,111)
```

How can we pass number codes if we have a string of codes as response?

Comment: Then make the `response` an array and convert the elements into characters...

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn your string into separate arguments: split by comma and spread:

```js
let response = '104,101,108,108,111';
let result = String.fromCharCode(...response.split(","));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yep, I've used both :)